# Asterisk Music On Hold loop

Tags: asterisk

I would need to be able to allow users to 'loop' through our MOH files.
Currently we have MOH set like this:

```
[moh]
mode=files
directory=/var/lib/asterisk/moh/custom
```

- is there a way to allow users to go to next file from that directory by clicking number 1 on keypad?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only variant i see without rewrite of asterisk is just stop/start moh based on key pressed

See features.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=1483

You also can create custom application which stream file and other app which on key pressed do "next track" on that app, but that will result alot of CPU usage.

See streaming:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+musiconhold.conf